# EXCEL: get criteria from a sumif formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, vba

I've been trying to find a way to get the criteria from a sumif formula that looks like this

```
=SUMIFS(N:N,G:G,"1670",H:H,"2016")
```

Every sumif has been hardcoded.... so I'm wanting to just pull out criteria1 in a cell (1670) and criteria2 (2016) in a cell. Either an excel solution or vba is fine

Comment: If `I1`=1670,`m1`=2016,then `=SUMIFS(N:N,G:G,I1,H:H,M1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the answer from @Floris, the below set of formulas gives your the criteria range and criteria in the formula. The below formula is used to remove the "=SUMIF(" & ")"

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(SUMIF_FORMULA),"=SUMIFS(",""),")","")
```

The `FIND` functions find the position of the commas in the formula. The last `LEN` function is required to get the last criteria.

`MID` command is used to get the text between 2 commas. the "+1" and "-1" in the `MID` function are to remove the commas from the output. Couldn't generate a google sheet as the `FORMULATEXT` function was not recognised.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, for completness you might want to add an excel 2010 version. I went for Function FT(mycell As Range); FT = mycell.Formula;
End Function; But you might have a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

With the appropriate version of excel you can use the `FORMULATEXT` function to get the string comprising the formula.

To get the criteria from this you have to make certain assumptions about the formatting of the formula - if you know commas occur only between argument it is quite easy to split the text on commas and extract; but in different locales you may find that a semicolon is used where you expect a comma; it is possible that ranges have commas in them; etc.

How robust do you need the solution to be?

Comment: appropriate = XL 2013 and higher

Comment: Thank you for the awnser unfortunatly I needed to go with a solution for xl2010 so I've opted to use Function FT(mycell As Range);
FT = mycell.Formula;
End Function